# What is the antiderivative of $f(x)=(a(K-x)^{1/n}+b)\times x^d$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

What is the antiderivative of the following function of x ?
$$\forall x>0, f(x)=(a(K-x)^{1/n}+b)\times x^d      $$

When $d=1$, there is an easy solution but in the case where $d$ is a positive real, i don't know.

Comment: a and b add nothing to the question. Take a look at the definition of the incomplete beta function. I think with a change of variables you can get there.

Comment: shame to me! You are right. I fall on this integral yesterday evening after a long day of work and feel tired... More prosaically, the question comes down to integrate $(K-x)^{1/n}\times x^d$. The result is effectively found in terms of the Beta function like: $$k^{1/n+d+1}\times B_{x/k}(d+1,1/n+1)$$ with $B$ being the incomplete Beta function...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Blitzer in the comments, here is the antiderivative of the function. first, b has no importance as $b x^d$ is trivial to integral. The question comes down to integrate $(K-x)^{1/n}\times x^d$. The result is in terms of the Beta function like: $$k^{1/n+d+1}\times B_{x/k}(d+1,1/n+1)$$ with $B$ being the incomplete Beta function such that:
$$B_{x}(a,b)=\int_0^x t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$$